# Is there a way to pass MSSQL table column as parameter to powershell function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, command-prompt, powershell-3.0

I have a below code in powershell where I am passing parameter is from the SQL CMS however I am willing to pass this servername from MSSQL tablename is there a way to achieve this.

```
import-module sqlps -DisableNameChecking  
function Test-SQLConnection{
    param([parameter(mandatory=$true)][string[]] $Instances)

    $return = @()

    foreach($InstanceName in $Instances){
        $row = New-Object –TypeName PSObject –Prop @{'InstanceName'=$InstanceName;'StartupTime'=$null;'currenttime'=$null}
        $servernameRDPcheck= $InstanceName 


        try

        {


        $Isconnected= (New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient -ArgumentList $row.instancename,3389).Connected


          $insertquery="  update dba.dbo.cms_validation set [IsServerRDPpingable]=1 where servername='$instancename' and convert(varchar(10),entrydt,111)=convert(varchar(10),getdate(),111)"

            Invoke-SQLcmd -ServerInstance 'HostedServer' -query $insertquery  -Database dba 

        }

        catch

        {

          $insertquery="  update dba.dbo.cms_validation set [IsServerRDPpingable]=0 where servername='$instancename' and convert(varchar(10),entrydt,111)=convert(varchar(10),getdate(),111)"

            Invoke-SQLcmd -ServerInstance 'HostedServer' -query $insertquery  -Database dba 

        }

    }
    return $return
}


$servers=@((dir "SQLSERVER:\SQLRegistration\Central Management Server Group\pih-win-sptlsql\Test\").Name)

$servers+="HostedServer"
Test-SQLConnection -Instances $servers
```

so instead of passing value from CMS as above i am willing to pass it from SQL table name as below and it should be looped while all servername in that table

```
$servers= select servername from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the way you can call above PS function and it worked for me

```
$Query = "set nocount on;  select top 20 servername from dba.dbo.tablename"
    $Servers = sqlcmd -b -S 'HostedServer' -d master -h -1 -Q $Query -W
    $servers+="pih-win-sptlsql"
    Test-SQLConnection -Instances $servers
```